# Add counter to property names in javascript

Tags: javascript, counter

I am trying to make my javascript script more dynamic but I am not really use to work with it, so I need help figuring out is it possible to add counter to the property names?

So I would like this code:

```
var title1 = document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsTitle1')[0].value;
var email1 = document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail1')[0].value;
var title2 = document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsTitle2')[0].value;
var email2 = document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail2')[0].value;
var title3 = document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsTitle3')[0].value;
var email3 = document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail3')[0].value;
var title4 = document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsTitle4')[0].value;
var email4 = document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail4')[0].value;
```

to do something like:

```
var inputFields = [];

for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
   inputFields.push({
       title: document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsTitle'+i)[0].value,
       email: document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail'+i)[0].value
       })
}
```

But i need this title and email to be title1, email1, title2, email2...

I tried:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    inputFields.push({
         'title'+i: document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsTitle'+i)[0].value,
         'email'+i: document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail'+i)[0].value
    })
}
```

and similar things like that, but no success. If there is a way to achieve that, please share your solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No you don't need to.

Comment: why can't you use `inputFields[i].title`? replace i for the index of the one you want to view

Comment: Using “numbered” class names is kinda nonsense to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to put a numeric suffix on the property names. You're putting the properties in different objects, so just use `title` and `email`, so your objects have a consistent set of property names:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
   inputFields.push({
       title: document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsTitle'+i)[0].value,
       email: document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail'+i)[0].value
   });
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var i;
var inputFields = [];
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   inputFields.push({
       title: document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsTitle'+i)[0].value,
       email: document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail'+i)[0].value
   });
}
console.log(inputFields);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<input class="requestRightsTitle1" value="title 1">
<input class="requestRightsEmail1" value="email 1">
<br>
<input class="requestRightsTitle2" value="title 2">
<input class="requestRightsEmail2" value="email 2">
<br>
<input class="requestRightsTitle3" value="title 3">
<input class="requestRightsEmail3" value="email 3">
```

---

But if you really had a reason to do it:

With ES2015+ syntax, you can use a *computed property name* for that:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
   inputFields.push({
       ["title" + i]: document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsTitle'+i)[0].value,
       ["email" + i]: document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail'+i)[0].value
   });
}
```

Before ES5, you had to create the object first and then add the properties:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
   var obj = {};
   obj["title" + i] = document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsTitle'+i)[0].value;
   obj["email" + i] = document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail'+i)[0].value;
   inputFields.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for that, but if the names are title and email, how would I get the value of let say email3? If all object have the name title and email.

Comment: @user2450639: You'd index into the array: `inputFields[2].email` in the above is `"email 3"` (because array indexes start at 0).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var temp_title = "title"+i;
    var temp_email = "email"+i;
   inputFields.push({
       [temp_title]: document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsTitle'+i)[0].value,
       [temp_email]: document.getElementsByClassName('requestRightsEmail'+i)[0].value
       })
}
```